# Being redirected to 127.0.0.1 from Wordpress/Apache installation with AMPPS

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, ampps

I have installed AMPPS (Apache + MysQL) with Wordpress on a Windows 10 computer to quickly setup a website. The website is working fine locally.

Now, the problem that I have occurs when I try to access the website from another computer. 
When I enter the server IP ( http://219.223.239.3/ ) on another computer, a main webpage show with the main directories:
[image]

This indicates that the other computer can connect to the server.

However, when I try to access the WordPress subdirectory on the server ( http://219.223.239.3/wp/ ), it redirects to http://127.0.0.1/wp/  and the webpage does not show. Hence, it seems that there is some configuration problem with WordPress or Apache.

[image]

To try to solve the problem, in Wordpress, I went to Settings>General, and I have set the "Wordpress Address" and "Site Addresss" to http://219.223.239.3/.  Moreover, I have edited the Apache configuration file to change "ServerName" to 219.223.239.3:80. But it still does not work.

Otherwise, all the settings should be the default settings of AMPPS.

I am not very familiar with Apache.

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check the wp-config.php file in the root of your wp folder. I had the exact same problem and it turned out the credentials for establishing a connection to the MySQL database I had running locally were incorrect.

In the Ampps management console (typically located at localhost/ampps/ in your brower), open up PHPMyAdmin and check the user credentials for the database connection.